# Какой отверткой(интересует точное наименование) можно открутить болты для снятия кулера на видеокарте 1030?

Tags: железо

Или я могу просто купить любой набор маленьких отверток и там скорее всего будет то что нужно?

Там очень маленькие болты.

Comment: начнем с того что 1030 это не видео карта, а линейка видео карт(с разными - производителем, объемом и типом памяти как минимум... не редко и габаритами\разъемами, разумеется от версии к версии могут меняться и болты). обычно на бэкплейте есть наклейка с маркировкой, по ней и ищите. но вообще да, нужная бита скорее всего будет в первом попавшемся наборе. в крайнем случае карту можно взять ссобой в магаз. если шляпка плоская\крестовая можно их открутить например кончиком тупого ножа(но в любом случае есть риск повредить кристалл, так что лучше отверткой и... сильно не затягивайте болты)